# Не работает исключение ValueError

Tags: python

я хочу узнать почему у меня не работает исключение. Судя по примеру из книги у меня должно вывести "Ошибка ввода :(", но вместо этого ошибка. Простите если вопрос глупый, просто я не смог найти ответ.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dtita\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\My successes.py", line 4, in <module>
    b = int(b)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'два'
```

```
a = input("Введите число: ")
b = input("Введите ещё одно: ")
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
try:
    print(a/b)
except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
    print("Ошибка ввода :(")
print(a/b)
```

Comment: Потому что исключение у вас в строке `b = int(b)`, которая ещё до блока `try`. Переставьте строку `try:` выше, до всех строк с преобразованиями в int.

Comment: Это не помогло(

Comment: Теперь ошибка
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
Думаю пока что как исправить

Comment: @Tellissan except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError) - TypeError у вас никак специально не обрабатывается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо было просто убрать последнюю строчку с `print()`. Не забывай, что всё, что может не получиться, нужно записывать в блок `try except`. У тебя может не получиться не только деление(делить на 0 нельзя), но и конвертация из строки в число(строку "два" не очень получается конвертировать в число, верно? :D ), поэтому блок с конвертацией строки в число **тоже** нужно перенести в блок `try except`. Удачи!

```
a = input("Введите число: ")
b = input("Введите ещё одно: ")
try:
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    print(a/b)
except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
    print("Ошибка ввода :(")
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь я понял)